# Android project, code got deleted during move of project folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, recover

So Ive worked on a small android game for the past months and it was located on my desktop. I figured it would be good practice to keep it in my workspace folder instead! So I moved the project folder to the workspace, imported it back into eclipse and boom... all code was gone. The classes code, the manifest.. all that was left was the assets. In the projects folder when opening one of the classes in notepad it is also gone.

Is there a way to recover the lost code or something? I dont understand why the code would dissapear just because I moved the folder?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the [Eclipse's Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse keeps a history of all files worked on in the following directory:

```
Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history
```

You'll have to search through it to find all your file. They might also not be the latest revision, but it has saved me many times.